# How to hide div on click and change html in another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple request(still learning javascript). I have a title div and 3 divs(with an anchor tag inside each) below it. Basically what I want, is when you click on one of the anchor tags, that that specific anchor tag should hide(actually its parent div), and the text in the Title div above should change. How can I do that? See [overly simplified example](http://jsfiddle.net/gGAW5/53/).

Comment: Inside the title div there is only one div with 3 anchor tags and not 3 divs.

Comment: oh sorry, i see now. was a bit tired when I wrote this. but you get the idea right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/gGAW5/54/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
        $("#myTitle").html( $(this).html() );
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Why not use .text() instead of .html() , just curious.

Comment: @freebird You totally can :) That's just in case there will be some formatting later in that links, i.e. a  `<span>` or smth.

Comment: Ok.Thanks.But if you only want to set the text then .text() should be better.Is it?

Comment: @freebird Yes, if you need just plain text then `.text()` is about 25% faster - http://jsperf.com/jquery-text-vs-html

Comment: @Zoltan. Great, thanks. Aprreciate your help. One more question, how to you toggle that changing text between two values, that is, if you click an a tag the first time, the title div shows "My Text". When you click another a tag, it shows "My Text 2", should you then click a third time, it should show the first text again(My Text 1). thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing jQuery DOM access and plain DOM access, which will cause some problems. Use the `$('#id')` selector instead of document.getElementById('blah');

To make a div disappear on click:

```
$('#mydiv').click(
    function()
    {
        $(this).hide();
        $('#otherdiv').html('new html');
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks David, good answer. Will remember that. I just though that since Jquery is a JS library, its like British English and American English, yet both understandable...Appreciate

Answer (score 1):

Not sure as to this is what you are looking for **[Check demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gGAW5/59/)**.

You are mixing javascript with jquery.
You can hide a element by something like this

```
$(this).hide();
```

Comment: Thank you Freebird...Appreciate your answer. You are right about the text, but as Zoltan said, I tried to keep it more general by using .html, if I would like to add classes and change child elements andsoforth

Comment: @DexterSchneider Happy to help:) Ya getting to learn from others problems is a good thing.